# How to remove eclipse project explorer above the editor?

Tags: eclipse, package-explorer

When I was working on a project for my program fundimentals class I somehow got this miniature project explorer above the editor in eclipse, I have tried to look for a solution on google but I don't think i'm asking the right question so this was my final place to go.

Here is a screenshot of my eclipse:
[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is the breadcrumb view.

To toggle it on/off:

- <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> (by default on Linux)
- Right click in editor and choose `Show in breadcrumb`
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd> to open up quick access (or click in quick access) and type `breadcrumb` and select the toggle command as in this screenshot:
  [image: quickaccess]
- Click this icon in the tool bar [image: breadcrumb]

Answer (score 0):

Yeah that is annoying, the workspace is cluttered enough. I was trying to simply minimize the explorer area so I could see the whole line of code and I eneded up activating this breadcrumb mode. Looks like:

FILES/PREFERENCES/SETTINGS/WORKBENCH/BREADCRUMBS/DISABLE